# missing values after imputation with mice R

Tags: r, missing-data, imputation, r-mice

I want to explore various classification methods on a data set with many missing data.
I tried imputing with cart method of mice since I was getting a singular error for the default method.
My problem is that, after imputing, I still have missing data.
What I did:

```
imputed_Data <- mice(stock, m=1, maxit = 5, method="cart", seed = 328)
data_det <- complete(imputed_Data)
```

Any insights greatly appreciated!

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. How exactly is your `stock` data formatted? How many columns have missing data?

Comment: All columns have missing data, 223 columns (features) and 4000+ rows (observations). If I just exclude all columns that have missing data I get an empty data set. All my values are numeric.

Comment: Also the imputed data have much fewer columns with missing but still I have missing values

Answer (score 2):

My issue was solved with setting ridge = 0.0001 and threshold=1.1 and I got the complete dataset